# How to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

How can I show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$, for distinct primes $p,q?$ The other inclusion is trivial.

I tried saying $$(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}} = \frac{\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q}}{p-q},$$ and since $p-q = -(q-p) \in \mathbb{Z},$ note that $(p-q)(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^{-1} + \sqrt{q}$ and $(p-q)(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^{-1} + \sqrt{p}$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}).$

I'm almost there.

Comment: you tried something?

Comment: You can see that $\sqrt{p}\sqrt{q}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$ by squaring $\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik See edit.

Comment: Hey, your attempt is even faster! Try linear combining $\sqrt p$ and $\sqrt q$ from $\sqrt p+\sqrt q$ and $\sqrt p-\sqrt q$

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1178284/242) for a quick way, and generalizations.

Comment: to finish off in your argument you really want to say $\frac12 (p-q)(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^{-1} + (\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$ and $\frac12(p-q)(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^{-1} - (\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt p+\sqrt q$.

Find $\alpha ^3=(p+3q)\sqrt{p}+(3p+q)\sqrt q$.

These equalities can be rewritten as
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ p+3q & 3p+q\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt p\\ \sqrt q \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \alpha ^3\end{bmatrix}_.$$

The square matrix is clearly invertible and its entries are in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and so are the entries of the matrix on the RHS, thus $$\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt p\\ \sqrt q \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ p+3q & 3p+q\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \alpha ^3\end{bmatrix}\in \mathcal M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb Q(\alpha)).$$

Therefore $\sqrt p,\sqrt q\in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 3):

We find  $$\sqrt{pq}=\frac12\bigl((\sqrt p+\sqrt q)^2-p-q\bigr)\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)$$
and then $$p\sqrt q+q\sqrt p= (\sqrt p+\sqrt q)\sqrt{pq}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)$$
so finally
$$\sqrt p= \frac{p(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)-(p\sqrt q+q\sqrt p)}{p-q}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)$$
and$$\sqrt q= \frac{q(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)-(p\sqrt q+q\sqrt p)}{q-p}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt p+\sqrt q).$$