# Using dimension arguments to prove the existence of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $V=<1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}> \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Using a dimension argument prove that there exists an $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $\deg(f)\leq4$ and $f(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=0$. Find $f$. Find $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}V.$

Any hints as to how to approach this exercise? **I know that the polynomial is $x^4-10x^2+1$.**

What I don't know is how to derive an existence proof from the dimension facts. The dimension of the space of polynomials of degree $4$ or less is $5$ and $\dim V \leq 4$... But I'm unsure how to relate these facts.

Comment: Should it be $\geq 4$? Otherwise, couldn’t you just use $f=0$?

Comment: $\deg(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: Oh, I see. So a proof by contradiction, if there is no such polynomial, the $1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4$ evaluated at $x= (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ are all linearly independent vectors in your 4-dimensional space $V$.

Comment: It is not undefined, in fact $deg(0)=-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ is a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$, see for example

[Is $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93463/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3)

[How to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264679/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-sqrtp-sqrtq-subseteq-mathbbq-sqrtp-s?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Basis for $\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 )$ over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663478/basis-for-mathbb-q-sqrt2-sqrt3-over-mathbb-q)

Hence there is a monic polynomial $f$ of degree $4$ such that $f(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=0$, namely the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. As you said, this polynomial is known to be $x^4-10x^2+1$:

[Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3 $ over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662080/find-the-minimal-polynomial-of-sqrt2-sqrt3-over-mathbb-q)